# C++ floating point subtraction doesn't appear to occur

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm trying to create overflow checks for addition (among other operations) and while the unit tests that I wrote for ints and longs worked fine, I've had some trouble trying to extend it to floats. The essence of the issue is expressed in the following code:

```
 1 #include "gtest/gtest.h"
 2 #include <math.h>
 3 #include <cmath>
 4 #include <cfloat>
 5 #include <float.h>
 6 #include <limits>
 7 
 8 
 9 class Test_FloatPfa : public ::testing::Test
10 {
11 public :
12 
13     virtual void SetUp(){}
14     virtual void TearDown(){}
15 };
16 
17 
18 ///////////////////////////////////Basic operator tests above, overflow tests below////////////////
19 
20 TEST_F(Test_FloatPfa, checking_for_FLOAT_sum_overflow)
21 {
22    float numberOne = std::numeric_limits<float>::max(); 
23    float numberTwo = 1.0; 
24    ASSERT_TRUE(numberTwo > numberOne - std::numeric_limits<float>::max());
25 }
26 
27 TEST_F(Test_FloatPfa, checking_for_FLOAT_sum_overflow2)
28 {
29 
30    float number1 = 1.0;
31    float number2 = std::numeric_limits<float>::max(); 
32 
33    ASSERT_EQ ( number2, std::numeric_limits<float>::max() );
34    printf("number1, number2 and limit -1 is: %f \n, %f \n, %f \n",number1, number2, std::numeric_limits<float>::max() -1);
35    ASSERT_TRUE (number2 > std::numeric_limits<float>::max() - number1 );
36 }                                                                                                                                                                                                   
37 
38 
39
```

Giving the following output:

```
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from Test_FloatPfa
[ RUN      ] Test_FloatPfa.checking_for_FLOAT_sum_overflow
[       OK ] Test_FloatPfa.checking_for_FLOAT_sum_overflow (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Test_FloatPfa.checking_for_FLOAT_sum_overflow2
number1, number2 and limit -1 is: 1.000000 
, 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 
, 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 
/home/adam/Projects/git/pfa-cpp-lib/PFALib/test/TEst_for_SO.cpp:35: Failure
Value of: number2 > std::numeric_limits<float>::max() - number1
  Actual: false
Expected: true
[  FAILED  ] Test_FloatPfa.checking_for_FLOAT_sum_overflow2 (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from Test_FloatPfa (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] Test_FloatPfa.checking_for_FLOAT_sum_overflow2

 1 FAILED TEST
```

It appears that it does not recognize the subtraction of one from the maximum floating point value, causing the inequality to evaluate to false. The write statement confirms that the max value minus one is not evaluated to less than the max value itself.

Thanks in advance for any insight that you might have.

Comment: Floating point numbers a weird.  It could be that `max` is so large that `max - 1` is not representable so it just rounds up to `max`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That's certainly the case. How many bits of mantissa would it take to store, say, 1e+308?

Comment: It makes sense to me that max + 1 would give undefined behavior, but why would a value be chosen for max that can't be used for a simple difference operation? If only straight comparison (and not comparison to slightly smaller values) cannot be done, then it seems like a smaller number that CAN be manipulated should also be included.

Comment: Further playing around has shown that I can't subtract ANY number from the variable set equal to max value and see the effect. HOWEVER, division does allow for this value to be reduced. This is so strange to me.

Comment: @FredLarson, pardon my naivety, but `1e308` only requires 1 bit of mantissa.  There would be 1 bit for sign and at least 9 bits for the exponent.  I would guess that the number of bits in the mantissa determines the precision of the floating point.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I guess I wasn't clear, but I mean to full precision. I think it's 1024 bits if you want to have all the way down to the ones place.

Comment: Does anyone know if the boost check_is_close method deals well with situations near the maximal value?

Answer (score 0):

Your programm is working right, there is no overflow of float value. Because your first number rounded to zero.

try to set first number to 1e30

Also try to code this:

(1e21+1e0)-1e21=0 but 1e21-1e21+1e0=1e0

Comment: Could you please explain which variable is "rounded to zero" and why?

Answer (score 0):

The IEEE754 single precision (32 bit) floating point type stores numbers with between 6 and 9 significant figures of accuracy.
To do your intended calculation with the subtraction of 1 accurately would require 39 significant figures of accuracy. This is well outside the range possible.

In short, this is because a single precision floating point value is stored in 3 parts:

- a 1 bit sign,
- an 8 bit biased exponent and
- a 23 bit mantissa.

The maximum value of a float is -

```
340282346638528859811704183484516925440 
with sign=0, biased exponent=254, mantissa=8388607
and hexadecimal representation 0x7F7FFFFF
```

The next highest number that can be represented will have the mantissa reduced by 1. This gives -

```
340282326356119256160033759537265639424 
with sign=0, exponent=254, mantissa=8388606
and hexadecimal representation 0x7F7FFFFE
```

Operations on floating point types don't wrap around like integers.  Instead they explicitly produce infinite or not-a-number 'NaN' values for out of range results.

This being the case, why don't you just do the operations in question and check it hasn't overflowed with with `std::isfinite` ?

---

For more of the basics on single precision floating point representation see ["Single-precision floating-point format"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

However, if you really want to understand the details of how floating point maths works and the implications for numeric programming you can do no better than reading ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1011/FPComp/floatingmath.pdf) by David Goldberg.